Efficient Pair Sampling with Pytorch
I have a dataset of around 150k images and 150k audios. Each image, has a corresponding audio. I want my network to learn to map one audio onto another using the image data.
When I create these source target pairs, my target is sampled from a subset of training data and must also fulfill a certain threshold criteria. Then the source target pair is created for training.
The way I am doing so right now is deriving the subset for target sampling and applying threshold in the getitem() of my custom dataset. This is taking far too long and creating a bottleneck during training.
I am unsure how to tackle this issue and speed up training. How can I solve this issue.
def _getitem_(idx):
   sourceimg, sourceaudio = self.data[idx] 
   Target_dataset = create_subset(sourceimg, sourceaudio)
   Iterations = 0
   While true: 
     targetimg, targetaudio = np.random(Target_dataset) 
     If cal_value(target_img) >= threshold:
       Return sourceimg, sourceaudio, targetimg, targetaudio
     Iterations+=1
     If iterations >= 10: 
       _getitem_(random.randint(0, len(self.dataset))

def cal_val(targetimg, sourceimg):
   sourceimg=np.load(source_mat)
   targetimg = np.load(target_mat)
   diff = np.abs(source_mat - target_mat)
   thresholded_difference = np.where(diff >0 , 1, 0)
   average_difference = np.mean(thresholded_difference)
   return average_difference

def create_subset(sourceimg):
  subarray=[]
  sourceindex1, sourceindex2 = os.path.basename(sourceimg).split("/")[1:3]
  for element in arr:
      elementindex1, elementindex2 = os.path.basename(element).split("/")[1:3]
       if(elementindex1 == sourceindex1 and elementindex2 == sourceindex2):
            subarray.append(element)
  return subarray

I have tried to do this during training. But with the amount of data I have, this is not efficient at all. How can I speed up training without increasing batchsize or num_worker in dataloader

Can you share the code of create_subset and cal_value?
Also, what should happen if no element of your subset satisfies the criteria?

How consistent/reproducible is the sampling? This seems like the sort of thing you could pre-compute once. ie for each idx, pre-compute all possible other idx values that meet the criteria

@YakovDan I have included those functions now. And if no element satisfies the criteria for 10 checking iterations, then we just sample another source from the dataset and ignore the current sample.

@Karl for each idx I have around 3000 possible other idx values. Currently I am using just a subset of 150k samples from my whole dataset (which has 7M samples).

To my question, can this be pre-computed? You could do a single up front batch process to create all possible valid idx pairs, then have your dataset simply pull from those values
